# Using a # (Hashtag) in a image name in scss/css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

Okay let's say i have an image named test#1234.png, while trying to import it as a:

`background: url('./assets/test#1234.png')`

I would get this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/test'

So it wouldn't even read out the whole name in the error, I've tried escaping the hashtag like test/#1234 and also percent encoding it like test%231234 but still no luck, anyone got an idea of what could fix this problem?

> NOTE: any other file name that doesn't contain a hashtag works.

Comment: Hashtags are used to indicate the start of the "fragment" in URLs. You shouldn't use them in your file names.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like this error is originating with SASS. Runing the `sass` command-line tool to compile a single SCSS file with a hashtag will work fine. In general, SASS does no checking of the filesystem to try and resolve paths, it only processes the syntax. The "module not found" error is being triggered by your build process, probably React.

Answer (score 0):

The hashtag is a reserved character for URIs (which denotes the fragment).

According to [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) [section 2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2), the reserved characters are:

> ```
> reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
> gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>             / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

And, importantly:

> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be percent-encoded **before** the URI is formed.

The percentage-encoding of the hastag comes out to `%23`, so instead of
`background: url('./assets/test#1234.png')`

You would be looking to target:
`background: url('./assets/test%231234.png')`

Comment: i've tried percentage encoding it already, i've mentioned it in my question, but thanks anyway.